# How to limit friend selection in FBFriendPicker?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm Using Facebook SDK in my app
I'm trying to limit friend selection to specified number in Facebook FriendPicker?
I'm trying this code:-

```
 - (void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:
      (FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
    {
        if ([friendPicker.selection count] >= 3) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = 
                [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                           message:@"Max number of friends selected."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
       clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

I get the `alert` but I cant dissmiss the `FBFriendpickercontroller`
Any idea why?

Comment: is self a FBFriendPickerViewController object?

Comment: no its view controller object

Comment: got it that was the problem. it should be self.FBFriendspickerViewController instead of self

Comment: ya thank you for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it !!!!!!!
solution was simpler than i imagined.
you `friendPickerController` is a tableView so we can set `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.

```
- (void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:
(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
{
    if ([friendPicker.selection count] <=3)
    {
        self.friendPickerController.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    }

if ([friendPicker.selection count] >=3)
{
    UIAlertView *maxFriendsAlert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Max number of friends selected."
                               message:@"no more friends can be selected,"
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:@"Buy more friends",nil];
    [maxFriendsAlert show];
    maxFriendsAlert.tag=1;

// disable friends selection
        self.friendPickerController.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }
```

Comment: Then the user cannot unselect a friend to go back under the limit. I'm trying to come up with a solution to disable only the cells that are not selected